# How do I tell to flyspell to ignore comment lines on git-commit-mode?

Tags: emacs, magit, flyspell

I usually change dictionaries when writing a git commit, however since I have a mapping to to change dictionary and run `(flyspell-buffer)` right after I see that flyspell goes beyond the commit message to check also comment lines starting with `#`.

**How can I tell *"flyspell, please ignore lines starting with `#` symbol"***?

I've read that I can use [`flyspell-generic-check-word-predicate`](https://superuser.com/questions/345084/how-to-exclude-in-flyspell-mode-and-flyspell-buffer/345461#345461) however my elisp is far from good :(, I came up with this:

```
(defun flyspell-ignore-comments ()
  "Used for 'flyspell-generic-check-word-predicate' to ignore comments."
  (not (string-match "^ *#" (thing-at-point 'line t))))
(put 'git-commit-mode 'flyspell-mode-predicate 'flyspell-ignore-comments)
```

However it doesn't work. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have `git-commit-turn-on-flyspell` in `git-commit-setup-hook`?
If so, that should set `flyspell-generic-check-word-predicate` to
`git-commit-flyspell-verify`, which ignores comments.

Comment: Indeed @kyle-meyer, I have that setup, checking `(describe-variable flyspell-generic-check-word-predicate)` gives something like `Its value is git-commit-flyspell-verify Local in buffer COMMIT_EDITMSG; global value is nil` but still commented lines are marked as flyspell errors (filenames, dir names, the `Untracked files` part, etc)

Comment: With `emacs -Q`, Magit 2.7.0, and `(add-hook 'git-commit-setup-hook
#'git-commit-turn-on-flyspell)`, I'm not able to reproduce the issue
(i.e. comments in commit messages are being ignored, as intended).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, thanks to @KyleMeyer for make me doubt about my configuration, the issue was that I had enabled flyspell in a `text-mode-hook`, and that was interfering with the config for the `git-commit-mode`. Removing `flyspell` for loading in the `text-mode-hook` solved the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for answering your own question. Your solution made me see an issue in my `.emacs`. I ran `flyspell-buffer` in the `flyspell-mode-hook` and this also gave me spelling errors in the comments of the commit buffer.